# Bluetooth not turning on?

Tags: bluetooth

I have a Vaio VPCCW21FX with a brand new installed Ubuntu 13.10 and I'm trying to connect a Wedge Mobile keyboard. So I went into the system settings, bluetooth and tried to turn it on but as soon as I click on the switch, it stays on for 1 or 2 seconds and then it goes back to the off position automatically...is there any compatibility issue? What can I do?

Answer (score 14):

First Check the Output for `rfkill list all`. It will tell you about the issue. If it's fine use:

```
rfkill unblock bluetooth # to start bluetooth
```

and

```
rfkill block bluetooth # to stop bluetooth
```

It has already solved your issue. I just wanted to post an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, check that your bluetooth was unlocked on `rfkill`.

```
sudo rfkill list
```

In case your bluetooth is `Soft blocked` you can unblock it by running the below command,

```
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

In case your bluetooth is `Hard blocked`,then try to find a `hardware switch` on your laptop to unblock it.

Comment: it looks like rfkill unblock bluetooth and rfkill block bluetooth are they same ??

Comment: avinash, with your command i get `start: Job is already running: bluetooth`
but with sushantp "unblock" command it is now working!! and i have the icon in the upper bar!! thanks :)
why it was "blocked"??

Answer (score 0):

Install and configure `urfkill`. This seems to work for my Dell:

```
# cat /etc/urfkill/urfkill.conf |grep '^[[:alpha:]]\|\['
[general]
user=root
master_key=true
force_sync=true
persist=true
```