# Bluetooth ceased functioning

Tags: bluetooth

I have been using a number of devices (phone, headset, speakers) connected to my Thinkpad which is running 13.04.

Today quite out of the blue (forgive the pun!) bluetooth disabled itself. Despite going into settings and clicking ON it refuses to activate bluetooth. I see an instantaneous list of the devices, then they disappear and bluetooth defaults to OFF.

Anybody any thoughts as to how I can restore bluetooth?

Comment: try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/383442/bluetooth-not-turning-on/383445#383445

Comment: Have you check out [Ubuntu don't detect my Bluetooth receiver, how to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/q/321750)?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

for starting bluetooth..